# How to decide/check whether some point belongs to a vector shape or not?

Tags: php, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I created some map (8000x8000) in photoshop. Every part of the map is created with custom shape tool and can be exported to *.ai file. So i exported one example shape to *.ai file, which has following contents:

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0
%%Creator: Adobe Photoshop(TM) Pen Path Export 7.0
%%Title: (map-small-paddington.ai)
%%DocumentNeededResources: procset Adobe_packedarray 2.0 0
%%+ procset Adobe_IllustratorA_AI3 1.0 1
%%ColorUsage: Black&White
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 7998 7998
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 7998.9998 7998.9998
%AI3_Cropmarks: 0 0 7998.9998 7998.9998
%%DocumentPreview: None
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
%%IncludeResource: procset Adobe_packedarray 2.0 0
Adobe_packedarray /initialize get exec
%%IncludeResource: procset Adobe_IllustratorA_AI3 1.0 1
%%EndProlog
%%BeginSetup
Adobe_IllustratorA_AI3 /initialize get exec
n
%%EndSetup
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 k
0 i 0 J 0 j 1 w 4 M []0 d
%%Note:
%Adobe_Photoshop_Path_Begin:<< /defaultFill false >>
*u
%AI3_Note:<< /operation /union >>
0 XR
4771.1153 4121.9960 m
4855.5878 4111.9732 4957.9582 4086.2029 5003.7736 4060.4311 c
5049.5891 4034.6599 5120.0382 3972.7994 5193.7738 3957.0505 c
5267.5089 3941.3016 5323.5226 3946.6539 5355.9339 3949.0778 C
5356.7559 3955.9301 5358.4651 3964.2284 5361.9409 3972.1987 C
5361.4717 3972.3317 L
5358.0990 3975.3640 5353.5658 3979.5329 5347.8721 3984.9663 c
5333.9035 3998.3003 5250.7315 4090.9969 Y
5162.4795 4165.2807 5134.5423 4193.2165 v
5106.6045 4221.1528 5064.0674 4221.7889 5022.1634 4227.5026 c
4980.2590 4233.2172 4968.8311 4237.6617 4932.0072 4254.1706 c
4895.1828 4270.6786 4843.1201 4292.2642 4827.8818 4298.6139 c
4812.6435 4304.9637 4796.1361 4316.3911 4778.9935 4340.5184 c
4761.8505 4364.6433 4745.9776 4385.5963 4728.8351 4398.9284 c
4723.2744 4403.2528 4716.9076 4407.1833 4712.3291 4410.3572 C
4681.6484 4314.8482 4661.9599 4219.4050 V
4662.8157 4217.2633 4684.8314 4162.2146 4701.6759 4132.7359 C
4710.9826 4122.7135 4771.1153 4121.9960 Y
n
*U
%Adobe_Photoshop_Path_End
%%Trailer
%%EOF
```

Now let's say I have two points: (4830,3780) which belongs to this shape, and (4480,3130) which doesn't. I know it because I checked it in Photoshop.

But my question is how to check every point I want programmatically? Is there a way to do it in PHP?

So question consists of two parts:

1. Load and read *.ai file
2. Check whether point belongs to the shape.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about shape intersections? Are there any present?

Comment: It can happen, but then point can belong either to first or second area - I don't care. So if I find this point in one area I will not be looking for it in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of to check inside/outside is rasterizing the image and using color.

Create a version of your map where the shape elements are all black, and the background is white. Save that as a JPEG. If you have PHP installed with the GD or Imagemagik extensions, PHP can pick the color out of an image at the coordinates you want:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('map.jpg'); // Import black/white map image
var_dump(isInside($im, 4830, 3780)); // bool(true)
var_dump(isInside($im, 4480, 3130)); // bool(false)

function isInside($im, $x, $y) {
  $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
  $colors = imagecolorsforindex($im, $rgb);
  $value = ($colors['red'] + $colors['green'] + $colors['blue'])/3; // Get average value
  return ($value <= 10)? true : false; // If average value is less than 10, this pixel is black (or very close to it), so is inside a shape
}
?>
```

I'm using a `$value <= 10` here rather than `$value == 0` since at the edges of your shapes, you'll get a little aliasing where the white background will blend into the black shape. The color value is from zero to 255, so 10/255 is still pretty black, and will make sure that if you target a pixel that's near a shape border, it will still evaluate properly.

Comment: That's the way I've never thought about... thanks - I will try your solution for sure and write some thoughts.

Comment: Maybe I will export this file to png (black shape on transparent background), so there will not be anti-aliasing problem.

Comment: @Carlos "transparent" versus "white" as a background makes no difference; near the edge of the shape will be some pixels that are not fully the "shape" color and not fully the "background" color, and you'll have to decide at what threshold you cut them off.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I chose transparent. As I took all the pixels which doesn't have alpha set to 127. So alpha 126 i still some color for me. Using this approach I don't need to count anything. I just take alpha and compare to what I want. Anyway - as you said - this is just a detail, and makes no difference.

Comment: Right; `alpha <= 126` would effectively be the same as `$value <= 253` for my script erring way on the side of grabbing too much rather than too little at the edges.